# Opening youTube in iOS not work

Tags: ios, youtube

I'm trying to create a youtube app in my app

Mt source code to load webView is:

ViewController header file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

ViewController implementation file
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)];
self.webView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
self.webView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

self.webView.center = self.view.center;

[self.view addSubview:self.webView];

NSString* embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K14RnTVt194"];

NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

}

When run, my app crashes and gives me the following screen

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, therefore problem is not because of webview. You can see "**Thread 1**" on left panel and last process before the crash on thread says "`__psynch_mutexwait`". You may get this error in some couple of situations like that;

1. Wrong set `NSTimer`
2. Wrong set or unmanageable `NSNotification` (especially Key-Value-Observer)
3. One of the objects tries to access `CoreData` objects on a background thread while using the main-threads context OR using the same managed object context on different threads (background or main) at the same time.

Try to check if you are doing something wrong one of this scenarios. Also, try to async operation what you are try;

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
    // The work that needs to be done on main thread
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the crash is in your stringWithFormat call, due to trying to replace the "%@" in your embedHTML with a NSURL object, instead of an NSString.